# Python overwriting dictionary instead of appending

Tags: python, json

Python noob here. Been staring at this for days, trying to make it work.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
import sys
import getpass
import itertools

password = 'mypassword'
def getusers():
  count = 0
  while (count < 1000):
    url = "https://blahblah/rest/api/latest/blah/member?groupname=some-group&startAt={0}&maxResults=100".format(count)
    request = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', password.format(password)), verify=True)
    data = json.loads(request.content)
    items = data['values']
    global active
    active = []
    inactive = []
    for i in range(len(items)):
        user = items[i]
        if user['active']:
            active.append(user)
            #active.append(user.copy())
        else:
            inactive.append(user.copy())
    count += 101
getusers()
print active
```

**count loop**: The API will only return 200 results per GET. Which is the reason for the count and loop. I'm trying to build a dictionary of 1000+ entries.

**startAt=**: defaults by starting at API record position "0". The count increases the position to 101, then 202, then 303... until it reaches position 1,000. So, records start at 0-101 and should append such that I have records 0-202, then 0-303, then 0-404, and so on.

**if user['active']**: 'active' is one of the keys that are returned for each user. If that key=True, send to the active dict, else send to the inactive dict.

**Current behavior**: 
When I print my "active" dict I get the last grouping of users instead of a total of 1,000 users. That last group of users starts at position 909 and end at position 1000.

**Expected behavior**:
When I print my "active" dict, it should contain nearly 1000 users with various keys/values. The active user dict should start at position 0 and end at positions = to the number of active users.

This is an example of what is returned from the JSON payload:

```
u'emailAddress': u'blahblah.com', u'key': u'bblah', u'active': True, u'timeZone': u'America/Los_Angeles'}, {u'displayName': u'Blah, Blah', u'name': u'bblah', u'self': u'https://blah.com'...]
```

Comment: You re-assign `active` to an empty list every time inside your while-loop: `active = []`

Comment: I don't know if this is the standard method, but a tactic I make use of a lot is to do try: my_list.append(new_item) except: my_list=new_item. This makes it unnecessary to initialize my_list to an empty list; if my_list doesn't exist, the try block will fail and the except block will execute, initializing the list to the first item. You do of course have to make sure that there isn't an already-created my_list that you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note in your code.

Firstly, calling *active* and *inactive* as dictionaries would be incorrect, since they seem to be lists, and not dictionaries. (see the difference between using {} and [])

Secondly, you are setting *active* and *inactive* to empty lists in each iteration of the while loop, which seems to be the cause of your issue. Every time the while loop iterates, *active* and *inactive* are assigned to be an empty list, and the list that was filled during the previous iteration of the while loop is *lost*. Instead, you can take the assignments outside of the scope of the while loop so that you only get to initialize those lists once.

```
def getusers():
  global active
  active = []
  inactive = []

  count = 0
  while (count < 1000):
    url = "https://blahblah/rest/api/latest/blah/member?groupname=some-group&startAt={0}&maxResults=100".format(count)
    request = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', password.format(password)), verify=True)
    data = json.loads(request.content)
    items = data['values']
    for i in range(len(items)):
        user = items[i]
        if user['active']:
            active.append(user)
            #active.append(user.copy())
        else:
            inactive.append(user.copy())
    count += 101

getusers()
print active
```

Comment: ahhhh, that's why! Thanks so much!